# Как создаются отчеты в Visual Studio на c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Имеются таблицы на Sql Server и приложение на c# которое отображает эти таблицы, но мне нужно создать отчет, который выводил бы разную информацию из всех таблиц. 
То есть, например, есть таблица Книги и есть таблица Авторы, мне нужно видеть в отчете Автора и список всех его книг. Таблицы связаны по ключам. Искал в интернете - никакой вразумтельной информации по созданию отчетов в Visual Studio я не нашел. Прошу Вашей помощи. Заранее спасибо

[image: Диаграмма]

[image: Приложение]

Comment: на dotNet с отчётами всё плохо, по крайней мере с бесплатными решениями, из платных можно посмотреть Telerik Reporting, Devexpress Reporting, Crystal Reports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверное, это будет не совсем ответом на вопрос, но все же оставлю его.

Зачем вы изобретаете велосипед? У Microsoft есть замечательный Reporting Service, где можно делать формы отчетов произвольной сложности.

Если не хватает функционала, то всегда можно написать на .NET либу и подсунуть в сервис отчетов.

Comment: А не знаете есть ли для Mysql похожего инструмента ?

Comment: @Сергей Вроде, можно извариттся и заставить его работать и с MySql https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2615/creating-a-ssrs-report-using-a-mysql-data-source/

Answer (score 2):

Для отчетов с SQL Server есть SQL Server Reporting Services и инструмент SQL Server Data Tools (такой вид Visual Studio).

Если же вы хотите в свое приложение встроить какой-то механизм, похожий на отчетный, то вам нужно будет реализовать всю логику - начиная от получения данных с сервера и до создания и заполнения формы вывода данных, либо найти готовые отчетные компоненты, которые можно будет использовать в тех же целях.